# Mongodb aggregations with django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

i am trying to develop a mongodb aggregation with django and python.

I have an atlas server with a database named 'sucre' with a collection named 'bdua'

In settings.py i have:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'morfeeweb',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.mongodb.net/morfeeweb?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
                'port': 27017,
                'username': 'xxxxxx',
                'password': 'xxxxxxxx',
                'authSource': 'admin',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
            },
            'LOGGING': {
                'version': 1,
                'loggers': {
                    'djongo': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'propagate': False,                        
                    }
                },
             },
        },
        'sucre': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'sucre',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.mongodb.net/sucre?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
                'port': 27017,
                'username': 'xxxxx',
                'password': 'xxxxxxxx',
                'authSource': 'admin',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
            },
            'LOGGING': {
                'version': 1,
                'loggers': {
                    'djongo': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'propagate': False,                        
                    }
                },
             },
        }
    }
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from random import randint

from django.db import connection

@login_required(login_url='/admin/login')
def consolidado(request):

    aggretation_sample = connection['sucre'].db.bdua.aggregate([
            {
            '$match': {'estado': 'AC', 'regimen': 'subsidiado'}
            },
            {
            '$group': { '_id': '$cod_EPS', 'Afiliados': {'$sum': 1}}
            },
            {
            '$sort': {'Afiliados': -1}
            }
            ])

    return HttpResponse(aggretation_sample)
```

It returns 'TypeError at /aseguramiento/
'DefaultConnectionProxy' object is not subscriptable'

Help please

Answer (score 0):

`django.db.connection` returns the `default` database ([see the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)). You want to use:

```
from django.db import connections

aggretation_sample = connections['sucre']...
```

Comment: Good, but now the response is 'AttributeError at /aseguramiento/
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'bdua''

Comment: What is `bdua` supposed to be?